# Convert for loop to if

Tags: c, if-statement, for-loop, avr

Hi. I have written a function that shifts LEDs to right.
I used `for` loop and I want to convert it to `if` statements.

```
#include <mega8535.h> 
#include <delay.h>   

void main(void) {
    int bits = 0b11111110;  
    int i;              
    int j;              
    PORTA = 0xFF;   
    DDRA = 0xFF;   

    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        for(i = 0; i < 8; i++) {  
            PORTA = ((bits << i) | (bits >> 8-i));  
            delay_ms(500);                                                      
        }                                                   
        PORTA = 0b11111110;                                  
    }      
    PORTA = 0xFF;                       
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you know that a loop repeats itself, but a if not? They cannot be "converted" into each other. Do you want a unrolled loop, maybe?

Comment: I have no idea what's your plan? Would it be useful if you try to do that?

Comment: You **can** use [goto](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html). But, you **should not** use goto.

Comment: `for` loop as the name suggests executes a block of code repeatedly until some condition is false. `if` on the other hand tests a condition and executes a block **once** if the condition is true. The control then flows down. It doesn't *loop* back.

Comment: there are no limit to repeat if statements. but i have now idea how a for loop can convert to if statements.

Comment: @user3087607 an `if` statement is **not** a loop like `for`, and `do`/`while`.  How do you convert a ball into a swing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    if(i==0){
    PORTA = ((bits<<0) | (bits >> 8));  
    delay_ms(500);
    i++;
    }
    if(i==1){
    PORTA = ((bits<<1) | (bits >> 8-1));  
    delay_ms(500);
    i++;
    }
    if(i==2){
    PORTA = ((bits<<2) | (bits >> 8-2));  
    delay_ms(500);
    i++}
    .
    .
    //so on up to i=7
```

Answer (score 1):

To unroll a for loop you would just copy and paste it's contents, each time replacing it with the current value of the iterator.

So

```
for(i=0; i<8; i++)                 
{  
PORTA = ((bits<<i) | (bits >> 8-i));  
delay_ms(500);                                                      
}
```

would become

```
//i=0
PORTA = ((bits<<0) | (bits >> 8-0));  
delay_ms(500);  
//i=1
PORTA = ((bits<<1) | (bits >> 8-1));  
delay_ms(500); 
//i=2
PORTA = ((bits<<2) | (bits >> 8-2));  
delay_ms(500); 
//i=3
PORTA = ((bits<<3) | (bits >> 8-3));  
delay_ms(500); 
//i=4
PORTA = ((bits<<4) | (bits >> 8-4));  
delay_ms(500); 
//i=5
PORTA = ((bits<<5) | (bits >> 8-5));  
delay_ms(500); 
//i=6
PORTA = ((bits<<6) | (bits >> 8-6));  
delay_ms(500); 
//i=7
PORTA = ((bits<<7) | (bits >> 8-7));  
delay_ms(500);
```

In VHDL for example, a for loop is converted to the equivalent unrolled loop.

Comment: is there any way to add if statement to your codes? i have to use if statements.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that GCC should unroll the loop if it thinks best with whatever optimization level.

Comment: @user3087607 wrap everything in `if (1) {` <code> `}`

Comment: @user3087607 why do you **have to** use `if` statements? Both `if` and `for` are there for their own uses. You should use what is fit and appropriate and not try to replace one with the other.

Comment: @ajay in all likelihood, the homework assignment specifies using `if` statements.